# MongoDB: Insert does not modify a list of documents?

Tags: list, mongodb, insert

Adding new value in a list with `insert` completes `ok` but document remains unmodified:

```
> graph = {graph:[
...       {_id:1, links: [2,3,4]},
...       {_id:2, links: [5,6]},
...       {_id:3, links: [7]},
...       {_id:4, links: [9,10]} 
... ]}
{
    "graph" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "links" : [
                2,
                3,
                4
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "links" : [
                5,
                6
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "links" : [
                7
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "links" : [
                9,
                10
            ]
        }
    ]
}
> db.test.insert(graph)
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.runCommand(
...    {
...       insert: "graph",
...       documents: [ {_id:5, links: [1,8]} ]
...    }
... )
{ "ok" : 1, "n" : 1 }
```

Yet getting elements after insert does not have a new inserted element:

```
> db.test.find()
  { "_id" : ObjectId("538c8586562938c6afce9924"), "graph" : [ 
       { "_id" : 1, "links" : [ 2, 3, 4 ] }, 
       { "_id" : 2, "links" : [ 5, 6 ] }, 
       { "_id" : 3, "links" : [ 7 ] }, 
       { "_id" : 4, "links" : [ 9, 10 ] } ] }
>
```

What's wrong?

**Update**

```
 > db.test.find()
 { "_id" : ObjectId("538c8586562938c6afce9924"), "graph" : [ { "_id" : 1, "links" : [ 2, 3, 4 ] }, { "_id" : 2, "links" : [ 5, 6 ] }, { "_id" : 3, "links" : [ 7 ] }, { "_id" : 4, "links" : [ 9, 10 ] } ] }
> 

db.test.update(
                 {_id : 538c8586562938c6afce9924},
                 {$push : {
                           graph : {{_id:5, links: [1,8]}}
                          }
                 }  

);
2014-06-03T12:35:11.695+0400 SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: Wrong way to give _id to MongoDB. The value is `'_id' : ObjectId("538c8586562938c6afce9924")`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the collection. Using `db.runCommand()` is not exactly the right way. It is essentially used for working in the context of database for performing tasks that extend to authentication, user management, role management and replication etc. The complete usability of `db.runCommand()` can be seen in MongoDB docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/).

The simplest way is using the `update` on collection. One of the reason why this query may not work for you is **not supplying the _id to MongoDB in proper way**.

**`_id : "ObjectId("538dcfaf8f00ec71aa055b15")" or _id : "538dcfaf8f00ec71aa055b15" are not same as _id : ObjectId("538dcfaf8f00ec71aa055b15") for MongoDB`**. The first and second ones are string type while the last one is an ObjectId type.

```
db.test.update(
                    {_id : ObjectId("538dcfaf8f00ec71aa055b15")}, //i.e. query for finding the doc to update
                    {$push : {
                               graph : {{_id:5, links: [1,8]}}
                             }
                    },  //performing the update
                    {} //optional parameters
);
```

But if you insist on using `db.runCommand()` then to get this same thing done you will need to write it as follows:

```
db.runCommand ({
                 update: 'Test',
                 updates:
                 [
                    { 
                       q: {_id : ObjectId("538dcfaf8f00ec71aa055b15")},
                       u: {$push : {'graph' : {_id:5, links: [1,8]}}}
                    }
                 ]
              });
```

What you have done is inserting something in a "graph" collection! You can do a `show collections` on your db and you will find that as a result of your incorrect `db.runCommand(...)` you ended up creating a new collection.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks! How about `insert` command? Does it exist? Where to read about commands that work in `mongo` shell? And what is `$push`?

Comment: @DarqMoth: Same story... use `insert` instead of `update`. Better to use `db.test.insert(...)`. `$push` adds an element to the end of an array. Since the field `graph` in your question is an array, we used `$push` to add this new item to the end of `graph` array. Another useful operator for arrays is `$addToSet` which adds the element only if it does not exist already in the array. You should google MongoDB docs and you will find everything you need. Also, to you I would highly recommend reading the available operators before anything so that you know what tools you have at your disposal.

Comment: Your `doc.runCommand update` version returns an error: `2014-06-03T12:27:02.148+0400 SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` I need some time to test other ideas you have suggested

Comment: Using `db.test.update` as you suggested also returns an error, please see my question update

Comment: @DarqMoth : For db.test.update() how are you giving the queried _id? You need to enter it as: `'_id' : ObjectId("538c8586562938c6afce9924)`. For the 'db.runCommand()` as well as 'db.test.update()` way, i have written my exact query above. See it. This is case sensitive so take care about the name of the collection you are using or the variable names etc.